# When are the @ResourceDependency annotations processed?

Tags: jsf

JSF provides the `@ResourceDependency` annotation that can be used with instances of `javax.faces.component.UIComponent` or `javax.faces.render.Renderer`.

My question now is: when and where are these annotations processed? I'm particularly interested in how Oracle's JSF implementation handles these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm particularly interested in how Oracle's JSF implementation handles these.*

They are processed via [`com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ResourceDependencyHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/application/annotation/ResourceDependencyHandler.java#ResourceDependencyHandler) when the component/renderer is being instantiated. The annotation metadata is however parsed once and cached applicationwide in [`com.sun.faces.application.annotation.AnnotationManager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/application/annotation/AnnotationManager.java#AnnotationManager). This is called by a.o. [`com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl#createComponentApplyAnnotations()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationImpl.java#ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%29) implementation which is called by a.o. [`Application#createComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#createComponent-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.application.Resource-) interface.